# Is there a way to get the data that is returned by `npm view <package name>`, perhaps by an official api?

Tags: npm

The data that is returned is in JSON format:

```
$ npm view react-router

{ name: 'react-router',
  description: 'Declarative routing for React',
  'dist-tags': { latest: '4.0.0', next: '4.0.0-beta.8', previous: '3.0.3' },
  versions: 
   [ '0.0.0',
     '0.0.1',
     '0.4.0',
     '0.4.1',
     '0.4.2',
     '0.5.0',
     '0.5.1',
 // ...
```

Is there an official api for this info?  I saw [one npm module called npm-web-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-web-api) but don't see an official published API.

Answer (score 2):

That information comes from the [npm registry API](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/ff53e341dc3cac2c7d750940e90e9b7080c9ef11/docs/REGISTRY-API.md#getpackage) ([format](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/ff53e341dc3cac2c7d750940e90e9b7080c9ef11/docs/responses/package-metadata.md)); your example can be found at https://registry.npmjs.com/react-router.

Comment: interesting... is it true that on the page https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router you can't really find the history (versions, release dates), but you have to rely on `npm view` or `https://registry.npmjs.com/react-router` ?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 As far as I know, yes.